# Return array of objects from VB6 to C# using Interop

Tags: c#, vb6, interop

I need to return an array of initialized objects from VB6 into C# using interop. My VB function looks like

```
Public Function CreateMyObjArray(ByVal MaxCount As Integer) As MyObj()

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim temparray() As MyObj
  ReDim temparray(MaxCount) As MyObj

  For i = 0 To MaxCount
      Set temparray(i) = New MyObj
  Next i

  CreateMyObjArray = temparray

End Function
```

Now, when I call this from C# after passing in the array by

```
Array InData = m_MyObjGenerator.CreateMyOjbArray(5);
```

I get a system.argumentexceptionerror where the message is

"Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.\r\nParameter name: typeName@0"

I also get this error if my function has no parameters. The function works in VB from a form. Likewise, the following function returns a MyObj just fine

```
Public Function CreateMyObj() As MyObj
 Set CreateMyObj = New MyObj
End Function
```

I know I can make a list of new MyObj's in the C# version and then .ToArray() it, but I would really like to get this working. Thanks.

**Solution**
Found out how to do it. I had to use tlbimp.exe without the /sysarray flag (which VS must use internally). After that, I was able to get everything working correctly. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off let's clean up that VB a bit:

```
Public Function CreateMyObjArray(ByVal MaxCount As Integer) As MyObj()     
  ''// MaxCount = 5 would allocate 6 array items with your old code
  ''// Also: do this in one line rather than with an expensive "ReDim"
  Dim temparray(MaxCount-1) As MyObj 

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To MaxCount -1 
      Set temparray(i) = New MyObj
  Next i

  CreateMyObjArray = temparray
End Function
```

Finally, you C# should look like this:

```
MyObj[] InData = m_MyObjGenerator.CreateMyObjArray(5);
```

Where MyObj is the marshalled type use when talking to your vb code.  As another poster suggested, you can set it to `Object` and step to it to let Visual Studio tell you what type to use exactly.

Comment: VS is importing it as system.array, your second code snippet leads to a compiler error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't expect it to compile, because "MyObj" is just a placeholder for your real type.  To get past the System.Array, try using Object[] there and then get visual studio to tell you the type of one element in the array.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry that I can't try out some code to really help you solve this.

Having said that, set `InData` to be an `Object`.

```
Object InData = m_MyObjGenerator.CreateMyOjbArray(5);
```

After that statement executes, use the watch window to determine the type of `InData`.
Modify the code (change the type of `InData` from `Object` to the type that you discovered using the watch window).

Hope that helps.